# Multiple foreign key lookups

Tags: python, django

I have the following models in my app

**Account**

```
class Account(CommonModel): # Accounts received from Client
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    reference = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.client} {self.reference}"
```

**Person**

```
class Person(CommonModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=choi.person_title())
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField()


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} {self.name}"
```

**AccountPerson**

```
class AccountPerson(CommonModel): # Account -> Person link
    account = models.ForeignKey("core.Account", on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="accountperson_account")
    person = models.ForeignKey("core.Person", on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="accountperson_person")
    contact_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=choi.contact_type())


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.account} - {self.person} ({self.contact_type})"
```

The AccountPerson model holds relationships between accounts and people (one person can have multiple accounts). I'm trying to return a query set containing a list of Accounts, and the Person they're linked to (if any). My background is SQL, so I'm thinking of a query that would hit Account -> AccountPerson --> Person, but I'm stuck.

I've tried prefetch_related() but I'm only returning details in the Account table - I'm unsure of how to access Person from there and put those fields into my HTML file.

**View**

```
def account_list(request):
    data = Account.objects.all().prefetch_related('accountperson_account')
    return render(request, 'core/account_list.html', {'data': data})
```

**account_list.html**
Code condensed for readability

```
...
{% for i in data %}
<tr>
<td>{{i.client}}</td>
<td>{{i.reference}}</td>
{% endfor %}
...
```

I'm currently in a position where my page loads, and I see the entries in my Account model, but that's it.

**Update**

I changed my view to this

```
def account_list(request):
    data = AccountPerson.objects.all().select_related('account').select_related('person')
    return render(request, 'core/account_list.html', {'data': data})
```

And I can now access fields in Account and Person in my HTML like so

```
{% for i in data %}
<tr>
<td>{{i.account.client}}</td>
<td>{{i.account.reference}}</td>
<td>{{i.contact_type}}</td>
<td>{{i.person.name}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I just want to check that this is the right way (or one of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the datamodel slightly to be more Django-y. Django has the concept of ManyToMany fields which is what you're trying to accomplish. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField)

You would define the `Person` model as you did and change the `Account` model to have a ManyToMany field (you could also switch it around, that won't matter).

You can also defined the intermediate model like you intended. Use the `through` argument on the ManyToMany for this.

You can use Related Manager to handle all lookups both ways: `account.person` and `person.account` (the 'account' part is set by the `related_name`).

```py
class Account(CommonModel): # Accounts received from Client
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    reference = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=AccountPerson, related_name='account')
```

Comment: Should the last line not read person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=AccountPerson, related_name="person") as I'm linking to the Person table?

Comment: Oh, yes, I was a bit quick with typing. I updated my answer

Comment: Oh, specifically the `related_name` should be 'account' because that is the name that you will use from the `Person` objects. So that part is correct, but the field reference was wrong.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.